# Villagers fail to breed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]In minecraft 1.14 I made a villager breeder but they don't want to. I gave them the requirements beds, bread and crops. But when they start to breed (like show the hearts) they just stop and show this weird thing above their heads any help?
(extra detail: 4 villagers, 7 beds, 6x6x3 square)

Comment: Have you made sure that mob griefing is on? I'm pretty sure villagers won't breed if it's off.

Comment: My mob griefing is on

Comment: What about how much food they have? they might not have enough food from the farm, in that case trading with them would be a good idea

Comment: well the farming plot is 6x6 and I gave them 3 bread and I have traded a little bit with them but i'll try and see

Comment: 1.14.0 or 1.14.4 or any other? The breeding mechanics changed A LOT between the minor versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is for 1.14.4 - it won't be fully valid for any prior versions as the breeder mechanics changed considerably in between them.

Make sure all the beds, including the extra for the children, are pathfindable to the adults in the breeder, and only to them at sleep time - remove the children from the breeder and make sure they cannot pathfind to the beds. (in particular, pathfinding doesn't equal them being physically able to walk up to the beds; for example trapdoors purposefully confuse the algorithm making the villagers think they can walk up to a block while in reality they can't; e.g your breeder's trapdoor hatch may be considered wide open by all villagers in the area even when it's closed.)

Also make sure to at least wait a little into the night after the children are removed and placed out of reach of their breeder beds - the beds are invalidated only after a failed pathfinding attempt is made - during the day no pathfinding attempts for the beds are made.

Last but not least, there's a specific set of circumstances where beds remain assigned even in absence of their prior owners. Breaking and replacing them solves the issue. For details on this issue, and a very in-depth analysis of the current villager breeding mechanics, reference Gnembon's [1.14.4 villager breeder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBrWG2DTBoE) video.

Comment: Gnembon's videos are fantastic, although they're also very technical - prepare to have your brain frazzled if you watch them!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for 1.16.1. Make sure there is enough empty space in the house and 2 blocks above each bed for the baby to jump. You also should make sure there is a door and you are not looking at the villagers while they breed.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough head space for the villagers, so they cannot breed. Even though they are willing, these villagers need more (1-2 blocks) of room to breed.